# How to remove words in corpus that start with $ in R?

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to do preprocessing in corpus in R, and i need to remove the words that start with $. Below code removes the $ but not the $words, I am puzzled.

```
inspect(data.corpus1[1:2])
# <<SimpleCorpus>>
# Metadata:  corpus specific: 1, document level (indexed): 0
# Content:  documents: 2
# 
# [1] $rprx  loading    mid .60's, think    potential. 12m vol  fri  already 11m today   
# [2]  members report success  see track record  $itek $rprx $nete $cnet $zn $cwbr $inpx 

removePunctWords <- function(x) {
  gsub(pattern = "\\$", "", x)
}
data.corpus1 <- 
  tm_map(data.corpus1, 
         content_transformer(removePunctWords))
inspect(data.corpus1[1:2])
# <<SimpleCorpus>>
# Metadata:  corpus specific: 1, document level (indexed): 0
# Content:  documents: 2
# 
# [1] rprx  loading    mid .60's, think    potential. 12m vol  fri  already 11m today 
# [2]  members report success  see track record  itek rprx nete cnet zn cwbr inpx
```

Comment: I'm not the best with regex, but maybe a "."? For example:   `gsub(pattern = "\\$.*", "", x)` ?

Comment: @shea   That would kill everything after the first $.  You only want to eliminate $ and the word characters that follow immediately.

Comment: @G5W thank you for explaining. I didn't know the ".*" would be _that_ greedy.

Comment: You may use `gsub("\\s*\\B\\$[[:alpha:]]+\\b", "", x)` to remove only whole words starting with `$` and having only letters after it.

Comment: why exactly was my questions downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression only specifies the `$`.   You need to include the rest of the word.

```
removePunctWords <- function(x) {
  gsub(pattern = "\\$\\w*", "", x)
}
```

Comment: Two-ish things, 1) this will remove all `$` even if they do not exist at the front of a word. 2) A barrier character may need to be added at the front of the regex to to prevent matching a dollar sign in the middle of a word, e.g. **bill$s** or **co$t**. OP doesn't specify the expected behavior for these scenarios but I thought it worth mentioning